# find in tshark/wireshark tcp sessions with unique value in filter - ldap.attributes

Tags: bash, python, wireshark, tshark, pcap

I need to find in tshark/wireshark tcp sessions with an unique value in filter - ldap.attributes

For example, in a picture
[image]

In red - value from filter - ldap.attributes. Some filter in the dump can be the same. It's like value **DistinguishedName**.

And I need to find in tshark/wireshark tcp sessions with an unique value in filter - ldap.attributes and export its sessions to new pcap file.

How can I do it with bash or may be Python? May be some like this function has in tshark.